# c++ templateの特殊化について

Tags: c++, templates

c++のテンプレートで

```
template<class T>
T get(std::string str)
{
if (std::is_signed<T>)
{
    return std::stoll(str);
}
if(std::is_unsigned_v<T>)
{
    return std::stoull(str);
}
if(std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
{
    return std::stold(str);
}
return T(str);
}
```

みたいなことをコンパイル時に、
整数なら

```
template<class T>
T get(std::string str)
{
return std::stoll(str);
}
```

浮動小数少数なら

```
template<class T>
T get(std::string str)
{
return std::stold(str);
}
```

それ以外なら

```
template<class T>
T get(std::string str)
{
    return T(str);
}
```

のように分けて実装したいのですが
いちいち型ごとに

```
template<>
int get<int>(std::string str)
{
    return std::stold(str);
}
```

とするのは面倒なのでもっと効率的な書き方は存在しませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++11にも対応させるなら以下のように型特性によるオーバーロードを使えばできなくもないですが、C++17以降への対応で良いなら`if constexpr`文を使った方がはるかに楽ですね。

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
T get(const std::string &str,
      typename std::enable_if<
          std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_signed<T>::value
      >::type * = nullptr)
{
    return std::stoll(str);
}

template <class T>
T get(const std::string &str,
      typename std::enable_if<
          std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_unsigned<T>::value
      >::type * = nullptr)
{
    return std::stoull(str);
}

template <class T>
T get(const std::string &str,
      typename std::enable_if<
          std::is_floating_point<T>::value
      >::type * = nullptr)
{
    return std::stold(str);
}

template <class T>
T get(const std::string &str,
      typename std::enable_if<
          !std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_floating_point<T>::value
      >::type * = nullptr)
{
    return str;
}


int main()
{
    auto si = get<int>("-123");
    std::cout << "si = " << si << "\n";

    auto ui = get<unsigned int>("123");
    std::cout << "ui = " << ui << "\n";

    auto df = get<double>("123.4");
    std::cout << "df = " << df << "\n";

    auto str = get<std::string>("xyz");
    std::cout << "str = " << str << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

戻り値に`enable_if`を使った

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<T>, T> get(std::string str)
{
    return std::stoll(str);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<T>, T> get(std::string str)
{
    return std::stoull(str);
}

// その他
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_unsigned_v<T> &&
    !std::is_signed_v<T>,
    T> get(std::string str)
{
    return T(str);
}
```

のような方法がありますが、これは具体的な型をつかっていないのでtemplateの特殊化ではなく、同名のtemplateを複数定義しているだけです。したがって、その他のケースを扱うところで、既に他で処理されているケースを除外しなければなりません。このため、特別なケースが増えると逆に面倒になってしまいます。また、新たにケースを追加したり削除したりするときにも、ミスをしやすくなります。

C++17が使えるなら、`constexpr if`を使うのが楽でいいと思います。

```
template<typename T>
T get(std::string str)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_signed_v<T>) {
        return std::stoll(str);
    }
    else if constexpr(std::is_unsigned_v<T>) {
        return std::stoull(str);
    }
    else {
        return T(str);
    }
}
```